# Analogue of fisher's exact test for one group?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, binomial-distribution, fishers-exact-test, hypergeometric-distribution

I understand that Fisher's exact test applies to testing whether the proportion of an outcome in one group, $p_1$, differs from the proportion of the outcome in another group, $p_2$. This could be like drug efficacy in group 1 vs drug efficacy in group 2.

Is there an analogue that works to test $p_1$ vs $p_2$ for the same group? The setting I'm thinking of is you have two classifiers making predictions on the same group, and classifier 1 has accuracy $p_1$ and classifier 2 has accuracy $p_2$. Given that classifier 1 got $k_1$ out of $n$ samples right and classifier 2 got $k_2$ out of the same $n$ samples right, how do we test whether $p_1 > p_2$ analogously to Fisher's exact test?

Comment: It sounds like you want McNemar's test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the samples where the two tests gave different answers, and write $m$ for the number of these and $m_1$ for the number where test 1 was postive and test 2 negative (and $m_2=m-m_1$ for the others).  Under the null hypothesis $p_1=p_2$, $m_1\sim Binomial(m,1/2)$, giving an exact test.

This (as @noah says) is McNemar's test. The $\chi^2$ approximation to the test is that $$(m_1-m_2)^2/(m_1+m_2)\sim \chi^2_1$$ giving one of the few tests you can easily do in your head.